# Why doesn't MSVC report a bug in duplicate anonymous union members?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unions, anonymous-class

I am trying to build the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    union {
        uint32_t cw            : 13;

        struct {
            uint32_t setting4  : 4;
            uint32_t cmd       : 9;
        };

        struct {
            uint32_t setting8  : 8;
            uint32_t cmd       : 5;
        };
    } control;

    return 0;
}
```

which defines a 13-bit code word which consists of several fields with overlapping interpretations.

I expect the build to fail due to a duplicate declaration of the `cmd` field in the two structures. Surprisingly, MSVC 2012 does not report an error.

As a sanity check, I tested the code in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HuIJGK) and the error did appear.

Note: it appears that when running the code and printing the content of the fields after assigning a value to `cw`, then `cmd` resolves to the first (9-bit) member.

Comment: Does MSVC even support the GNU extension "anonymous struct"? Otherwise, it failing would not be too surprising.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - I thought these are standard features now. Also, if it does not support it, then I'd expect some kind of error.

Comment: I do not think that's standard C++. Why MSVC does not report an error I don't know.

Comment: If this situation is not clearly spelled out in the standard, then MSVC 2012 may have been programmed to naively choose the first value that matches and ignore any conflicts. Not a great choice, but very possible.

Comment: @BaummitAugen More the other way around. GCC supports the Microsoft anonymous struct extension. The Windows API headers use them pretty extensively. This is extension is now standardized in C11, but I don't know about C++.